# Why Spring Boot @Value read property value as 1 instead of 001?

Tags: spring-boot, properties

I have a property `homework.directory` with value `001` in `application.yml` like:

```
homework:
    directory: 001
```

But when I use @Value to inject this value into a `String` variable, I got `1` not `001`. Below is my code.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class PropertyTest {
    @Value("${homework.directory}")
    String directory;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext container = SpringApplication.run(PropertyTest.class);
        PropertyTest test = container.getBean(PropertyTest.class);
        System.out.println(test.directory);
    }
}
```

Thanks!

**EDIT**: I change the value from `001` to `"001"`, the printed value become correct. I guess that Spring Boot will evaluate digital string as number and then ignore the prefix `0`. Am I right?

Answer (score 0):

I guess it is `yaml` that treats them as octal. If you have your configurations in `.properties` I guess you need not do this.